# H2 JDBC Syntax error when executing persistent SQL commands into h2db

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq, h2db

My appication uses Java + jOOQ + H2DB.
I have created two `Threads` to continue execution.

Thread 1: Insert records continuously into table A

Thread 2: Select limit of 10000 consecutive records from table A

When I run my application, sometimes the `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException` is thrown,
SQL statements have been changed by some characters **PUBLIC.SCENAR  ऀ☀䙉O_EXECUTE_LOG**

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "PUBLIC.SCENAR  ऀ☀䙉O_EXECUTE_LOG.TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME" not found; SQL statement:
select "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."LOG_SEQ", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."USER_ID", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."EXECUTE_DIV", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."EXECUTE_SCENARIO_ID", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."EXECUTE_START_TIME_UTC", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."EXECUTE_END_TIME_UTC", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."EXECUTE_START_TIME_LOCAL", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."EXECUTE_END_TIME_LOCAL", "PUBLIC"."SCENAR  ऀ☀䙉O_EXECUTE_LOG"."TOTAL_RUNNING_TIME", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."LOG_FOLDER_NAME", "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."RESULT_DIV" from "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG" where "PUBLIC"."SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG"."LOG_SEQ" = cast(? as int) for  [42122-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.getColumnException(ExpressionColumn.java:176)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:158)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:1245)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:689)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:627)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:270)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Rather, it is `PUBLIC.SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG`

If I only run thread 1 or thread 2 then this error does not arise

From where did this error arise?

**UPDATE:**

Helper class

```
    private static Connection h2Connection;
    private static DSLContext dslContext;
    private static Server server;


    public static DSLContext getDSLContext() throws Exception {
        if (dslContext == null) {
            dslContext = new DefaultDSLContext(getConnection(), SQLDialect.H2, settings);
        }
        return dslContext;
    }

    private static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        if (h2Connection == null) {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            String url = String.format("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/%s;", (DB_PATH.isEmpty() ? OUTPUT_PATH + folderPath + H2DB_PATH : DB_PATH)) +
                    String.format("USER=%s;", USER_NAME) +
                    String.format("PASSWORD=%s;", PASSWORD);

            System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "false");
            server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
            System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
            try {
                h2Connection = new JdbcConnection(url, new Properties());
                return h2Connection;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Error fetching connection", ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return h2Connection;
    }
```

Main class

```
Thread insertExecuteLog = new Thread(() -> {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            Random random = new Random();
            scenarioExecuteLogRecordInsert.setLogSeq(random.nextInt(10000000 - 4000000) + 4000000);
            JooqScenarioExecuteLogHelper.insertExecuteLog(scenarioExecuteLogRecordInsert);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});

Thread getExecuteLog = new Thread(() -> {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            ScenarioExecuteLogRecord[] listScenarioExecuteLog2 = JooqScenarioExecuteLogHelper.getListScenarioExecuteLog();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});

insertExecuteLog.start();
getExecuteLog.start();
```

SQL

```
public static ScenarioExecuteLogRecord[] getListScenarioExecuteLog(){
    DSLContext dslContext = JooqRpaSysDBHelper.getDSLContext();
    return dslContext.selectFrom(SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG)
        .orderBy(SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG.LOG_SEQ)
        .limit(10000)
        .fetchArray();
}

public static void insertExecuteLog(ScenarioExecuteLogRecord scenarioExecuteLogRecord){
    DSLContext dslContext = JooqRpaSysDBHelper.getDSLContext();
    dslContext.insertInto(SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG)
        .set(SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG.LOG_SEQ, scenarioExecuteLogRecord.getLogSeq())
        .set(SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG.USER_ID, scenarioExecuteLogRecord.getUserId())
        .set(SCENARIO_EXECUTE_LOG.EXECUTE_DIV, scenarioExecuteLogRecord.getExecuteDiv())
        .execute();
}
```

Comment: what resources do the the two threads share? are they using the same connection? perhaps the same prepared statement? can you share the code?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Two thread using the same Connection and DSLContext. They are static variable in the Helper class. I have updated the source code

Comment: Does this also occur if you have connection per thread?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No, that didn't happen when I used separate connections for each thread